# installation of pdo_pgsql on centos

Tags: postgresql, pdo, installation, pecl

I have install pdo_pgsql by running command below command on CentOS 5.7

```
pecl install pdo_pgsql
```

But it does not show at phpinfo page as an installed extension. The only info i see at there is

```
--with-pgsql=shared
```

have i missed anything?

At my machine php 5.3.3 is installed.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
--with-pgsql=shared
```

Indicates, that the default PostgreSQL extension was compiled as a module when your PHP was compiled.

Pecl doesn't simply install a module, it also compiles them from source and therefore has a lot of dependencies which are not automatically resolved.

If pecl doesn't output any error message you probably simply need to add the extension in your `/etc/php.ini`

```
extension=pdo_pgsql.so
```

Did you try to install the extension using yum?

**EDIT**

To remove an pecl extension

```
sudo pecl uninstall extension_name
```

Don't forget to restart Apache after your installation so any changes actually have an effect.

```
sudo service httpd restart
```

Comment: I have added the above line in php.ini but still it did not work. Moreover i did not try using Yum. But let me try it and get back...BTW how can we uninstall pdo_pgsql installed with pecl ?

Answer (score 1):

I used this command to install `php-pgsql` extension for PHP:

```
sudo yum install php-pgsql
```

After that I saw `pdo_pgsql` in the command's output:

```
php -m
```